# onRowSelect is triggered along with onRowDblClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dhtmlx

I have dhtmlx grid and I attach two events to it:

```
var click_flag = false;
        dhxGrid.attachEvent("onRowDblClicked", function (rowId, cellIndex) {
            click_flag = true;
            ...                
        });
        dhxGrid.attachEvent("onRowSelect", function (rowId, cellIndex) {
            if (!click_flag) {
                ...     
            }           
        });
```

But onRowSelect gets triggered always, even when I double click a row of the grid. Is there a way I can stop it from executing? I tried with click_flag but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by browser's behavior ( dbl-click action generates single click event as well ) 
You can separate both events with a bit of custom timing logic, like next

```
var click_timer;
dhxGrid.attachEvent("onRowDblClicked", function (rowId, cellIndex) {
    if (click_timer) clearTimeout(click_timer);
    ... actual ondblclick code here ...
});
dhxGrid.attachEvent("onRowSelect", function (rowId, cellIndex) {
    click_timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        ... actual onrowselect code here ...
    }, 250);
});
```